# Magento: where do I find the implementation of GETTER: Mage_Sales_Model_Order::getTotalPaid()?

Tags: magento

My payment processor confirms that my clients paid the correct amount, while magento (in admin order info) "says" that the order still has a totalDue of 1 cent.
I really want to see how this GETTER: Mage_Sales_Model_Order::getTotalPaid() looks like, but I can not find the implementation.

Comment: Check Varian_Object ( __get ) .. the total_paid attribute is loaded from getter method of Varian_Object. Offcourse, It must be save in the database table, Check the Order entity table for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a running installation atm, but i assume that totalPaid is just a standard attribute that's retrieved by magentos magic accessor in `Varien_Object` (`__call`).

Comment: Yes, I reached to that magic function, but how is the attribute calculated? There is nothing like that in a __construct method or somethig.

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit set or get for that kind of variable.

The data is set in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::pay();` and/or `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment::pay()`

The error come from the creation of the invoice, a rounding issue due to tax configuration (tax on quote total instead of tax on each product row).

Comment: From what I see, there is a problem with some inconstancy in calculation of totals in adminhtml templates (at least) (YES! There is a lot of math inside templates - as in order info - items list).

Comment: The payment processor receives the correct totals (the customer pays the correct amount).

Comment: I will take a look at Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment::pay() too. Thank you!